# How to restrict file size when using AjaxFileUpload and how to communicate that to user using client javascript

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit, filesize

We have an aspx page with AjaxFileUpload extender, 
which is used to asynchronously upload some image files to server.

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
                    OnUploadComplete="UploadComplete"  
                    OnClientUploadComplete="UploadCompleteClient" /
```

>

And we have to keep the file size of uploaded file to a certain limit.
for that we are currently using the following code on serverside as

```
protected void UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.FileSize <= fileSizeLimit)
        {
            AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
    }
```

and on client side as

```
function UploadCompleteClient(sender, args) {
        if (parseInt(args._fileSize) > fileSizeLimit) {
            alert("file exceeds file size limit");
        }
```

Now when a file is above the "fileSizeLimit" file is not saved on server.
And client side alert show the user that file size is exceeded.
But the issue now is **AjaxFileUpload extender status messages** show all file are uploaded successfully.

Is there anyway we can show alert error message and **show proper AjaxFileUpload extender status messages**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UploadCompleteClient` in client side to check if file size is exceeded, then show error message. Following is the `js` for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function UploadCompleteClient(sender, args) {
  var filesize = args.get_fileSize();
  var fileId = args.get_fileId();


  var status = document.getElementById('AjaxFileUpload1_FileItemStatus_' + fileId);

  if (parseInt(filesize) > fileSizeLimit) {

    alert("file exceeds file size limit");
    if (status.innerText) {
      status.innerText = " file exceeds file size limit ";
    }
    if (status.textContent) {
      status.textContent = " file exceeds file size limit ";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```